# Technical term for representing object of a presheaf determined by a left-adjoint?

Tags: reference-request, ct.category-theory, soft-question, notation, mathematical-writing

If $\mathcal{D}$ is a locally-small category, then a functor $F\colon\mathcal{C}\rightarrow\mathcal{D}$ has a right-adjoint if and only if for each object $d$ of $D$, the presheaf $$\mathcal{C}^{\mathrm{op}}\xrightarrow[c\,\mapsto\, \mathcal{D}(F(c),d) ]{}\mathsf{Set}$$ is representable.

- Is there a usual technical term for, given $d$, a *representing object* of the aforementioned presheaf? Or rather, usual or not, have you ever *encountered* a specialized term for this, and which do you *recommend*?

<sub>Remarks. Whether any specialized term is needed, is debatable of course, and not the question. There are situations where it is useful to have a term for it, to facilitate discussing the issue, in particular in expositions. Saying ``representing object  of $F$'' would be nonsensical. Of course, one can just describe it the way I did, but is there a specialized technical term for this representing object?

For want of a standard term, and despite the connotations of "law" and similarity to another, usual notation, I always used to call and denote "the" family</sub>

$\mathrm{Ob}(\mathcal{D})\ni d\mapsto $(a representing object of the relevant presheaf) $\in$ $\mathrm{Ob}(\mathcal{C})$

"the" $\mathrm{Law}(F)$, for "left-adjoint witnesses of $F$", since if a family $\mathrm{Law}(F)$ exists, then $F$ is a left-adjoint, and such a family of objects is something of a certificate for its being a left-adjoint.

- Do you agree that, strictly speaking, it would *not* be in accordance with the definition of "the" in [the](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/generalized+the) to refer to "the law of $F$"?

<sub>After all, each "component" of $\mathrm{Law}(F)$ is determined only up to isomorphism in the category $\mathcal{D}$, and the feature of any two laws being determined up to *unique* isomorphism seems to be totally lacking.</sub>

Comment: I don't know of a term. In a given discussion I might call it "a model for the right adjoint evaluated at d". If you re-write the functor F as a correspondence over the poset [1], then you might call such a representing object the 'source of a Cartesian arrow whose target is d'.

Comment: Mac Lane in Categories for the Working Mathematician wisely refers instead to a *universal arrow* from $F$ to $d$, thus placing emphasis on the fact that it's not just a representing object $c'$ involved but an ordered pair $(c' \in Ob(C), Fc' \to d)$ which is universal, i.e., terminal (as an object in the comma category $F \downarrow d$). This takes care of your other question too since we can speak of "the" universal arrow in the sense you link to.

Comment: So my answer to your "strictly speaking" is yes, I see the point you're making, but I think of this as really just one of those abuses of language that we all learn to tolerate when, for example, we use a single letter $X$ to denote a measure space which is actually an ordered triple $(X, \Omega, \mu)$. So a "representing object" $c'$ should really be regarded as a shorthand for an ordered pair $(c', \theta: Fc' \to d)$ that is the universal thing and that by all rights is what we mean by "the representing object".

Comment: Finally, I'd prefer to say not that the object $c'$ is a "witness", but it's the $\theta$ (in the notation of the preceding comment) that witnesses the representability by $c'$. Thus $\theta \in D(F c', d)$ is a witnessing term or element, similar to other uses of the word in category theory and type theory.

Comment: Another possibility is a "cofree object": https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/free+object

Comment: @DylanWilson: what is meant by "correspondence over the poset [1]"?

Comment: @ToddTrimble: useful comments, many thanks. I was curious whether in there is a was a specialized term in the context of right-adjoints. But, yes, using the standard terminology of universal arrows seems the most sensible thing to do. Would you mind making the comments an answer so I can check the question as answered?

Comment: Yeah that wasn't clear: I mean consider the category whose objects are either objects of C or objects of D and morphisms between an object of C and an object of D are Hom(Fc,d). This category has a projection to [1] where you send C to 0 and D to 1. That projection map is a cocartesian fibration. The data of a Cartesian arrow in this category is equivalent to the data of what we've at this point agreed to call a 'universal arrow'.

Comment: (Or I should say 'Cartesian arrow covering the non-identity arrow in [1]')

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As requested, I'll turn my comments into an answer. There were two questions, the first being what we call the representing object if a presheaf $c \mapsto \mathcal{D}(F c, d)$ is representable, and the second being whether the "the" in "the representing object" is justified.

Based on some other recent discussions, it's the second question that I thought more critical to address. My answer is that a representation consists not only of a representing object $c'$ but also a *specified isomorphism* $\mathcal{C}(-, c') \stackrel{\sim}{\to} \mathcal{D}(F-, d)$ (as opposed to an object $c'$ with the property that there exists such an isomorphism). By the Yoneda lemma, the specified isomorphism is given by an element $\theta \in \mathcal{D}(Fc', d)$, variously called a *universal element* or a *universal arrow* $\theta: Fc' \to d$. Thus Mac Lane in Categories for the Working Mathematician speaks of a universal arrow from $F$ to $d$ as consisting of a certain ordered pair $(c' \in Ob(\mathcal{C}), \theta: F c' \to d)$, one that exhibits or witnesses the representability of $\mathcal{D}(F-, d)$, or equivalently, as "the" terminal object of a comma category $F \downarrow d$.

(That comma category formulation is technically useful, as not only does it justify the word "the" in that nLab sense -- terminal objects being always unique up to unique isomorphism -- but re-orients attention to the fact that all universal mapping problems are about is constructing initial or terminal objects in suitable categories. So if you read for example about adjoint functor theorems, that's how you should interpret what is going on in those technical hypotheses like solution-set conditions: one is trying to replace the construction of an initial object in some (usually large) category $\mathcal{A}$ as the *limit* of the *large* diagram $1_\mathcal{A}: \mathcal{A} \to \mathcal{A}$ by a limit over a small diagram that happens to be cofinal in the large diagram. That's all it is.)

Getting back to terminology and what you call the representing object: you could either follow Mac Lane and refer instead to the universal arrow from $F$ to $d$, which is fairly short and clear and has the right emphasis, or you could adapt the suggestion made by Mike Shulman and say something like "the cofree object (relative to $F$) cogenerated by $d$" (or "on $d$" or "over $d$", leaving off the "cogenerated"). As usual in such things, that's a slight abuse of language since, analogously, we don't consider a free group on a set $X$ as a just a group $G$, but rather as a group $G$ together with a function $X \to UG$ satisfying the appropriate universal property. But as long as that language abuse is clearly understood, that alternative terminology seems acceptable.

Comment: Thanks. The "an A consists not only of a B, but also of a specified C (as opposed to a D such that there exists a C)" pattern is useful. One could think of a list of such statements illustrating that, despite its focus on intrinsicality, category theory demands an additionally specified "part" of something. Basic example, modelled on your sentence: a _constant functor_ consists not only of a _functor such that any two of its values are equal_, but also of a specified _object giving its value_. Here, there is another aspect: that the "intrinsic definition" would speak of equality of objects.

Comment: I don't understand your last sentence, but we can discuss this elsewhere.

Comment: It is probably more useful to do this here, since there is not much to be explained: I was referring that one might be tempted (especially when weaned on classical analysis, with theorems like "locally-constant=>constant") to "define" a _constant functor_ intrinsically (whatever that means in general; here it means: without ever mentioning the value of the functor), as a functor $F$ such that $F(o)=F(o')$ for all objects $o$ and $o'$. Someone coming from analysis might even consider this somehow better than mentioning a value explicitly. The latter is what was meant by "intrinsic definition".

Comment: One way to define constant functor without speaking of objects is to use "the terminal category 1" as some kind of logical primitive and say _constant functor_ $=$ _a functor of the form $1\rightarrow \mathsf{C}$_.

Comment: Or, more precisely, ( _constant functor $\mathsf{C}_0\rightarrow\mathsf{C}_1$_ )  $=$ ( _a functor of the form $\mathsf{C}_0\xrightarrow[]{!} 1 \xrightarrow[]{}\mathsf{C}_1$_ ) . This is standard, and slightly off topic, of course---just mentioning it to round out this thread.

Answer (score 2):

Todd Trimble’s answer makes very good points about representing objects/arrows in general.  However, in your specific case — an object $c \in \newcommand{\C}{\mathbf{C}}\newcommand{\D}{\mathbf{D}}\C$ such that $\C(x,c) \cong \D(Fx,d)$, naturally in $x \in \C$ — **it is generally known as the *cofree object* on $d$**, as Mike Shulman mentions in comments.

This terminology is absolutely standard in the case where $F$ is some kind of forgetful functor; one has for instance [cofree comodules](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/682892/cofree-comodules-and-embedding) over various sorts of Hopf-/bi-/co-algebras (in print, see e.g. Prop. 2.5.8 of Hovey’s book *Model Categories*), [cofree coalgebras](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1631890/cofree-coalgebra-explicit-description-from-its-universal-property?rq=1), and [cofree comonads](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/free-4.12.4/docs/Control-Comonad-Cofree.html).  For arbitrary $F$, it’s slightly less universal, but I’ve certainly heard it — and if one wants some term for this purpose, it seems like the obvious choice.

Comment: Actually, I mentioned this as well in my answer. :-)

Comment: @ToddTrimble: yes, I saw — I wanted to emphasise this more than you do, though, and add references, since I think *cofree* is really the standard answer to OP’s specific question, not just one possibility.  Your answer gives many more important general points, addressing the general discussion in the question, but I feel that this — as the overall answer — deserved being stated a bit more strongly.

Comment: Fair enough! +1.